# Running apriori in R does not result in any rules.

Tags: r, apriori, market-basket-analysis

I am trying to run apriori on my data set but get no rules.
Here is what I see.

```
> rules <- apriori(mydata, parameter = list(supp=.01))
Apriori

Parameter specification:
 confidence minval smax arem  aval originalSupport support minlen maxlen target   ext
        0.8    0.1    1 none FALSE            TRUE    0.01      1     10  rules FALSE

Algorithmic control:
 filter tree heap memopt load sort verbose
    0.1 TRUE TRUE  FALSE TRUE    2    TRUE

Absolute minimum support count: 700 

set item appearances ...[0 item(s)] done [0.00s].
set transactions ...[1335 item(s), 70000 transaction(s)] done [0.01s].
sorting and recoding items ... [11 item(s)] done [0.00s].
creating transaction tree ... done [0.00s].
checking subsets of size 1 done [0.00s].
writing ... [0 rule(s)] done [0.00s].
creating S4 object  ... done [0.00s].
> inspect(rules)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps your dataset simply does not contain any association rules.

Comment: From `?apriori`: _"The default behavior is to mine rules with support 0.1, confidence 0.8, and maxlen 10."_ - adjust the confidence value? You could provide the data set to stop guess work.

Answer (score 2):

the reason you have no rules is because of the data and not the code. What I mean with this is that the parameters you asked for (support =0.1) and the default parameter you left (confidence = 0.8) are too high for the data you have.

This is probably because your data is too heterogeneous. The solution would be to reduce the parameters. Probably it would work with something like:

```
rules <- apriori(mydata,parameter(list=(support=0.001,confidence=0.3)
```

Hope it helped!